# Add excerpt_length to the Understrap WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, wordpress-theming, addition

I am trying to add an excerpt length of e.g. 50 to the following Understap theme code.
https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/main/inc/extras.php

The specific code is:

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'understrap_all_excerpts_get_more_link' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'understrap_all_excerpts_get_more_link' ) ) {
    /**
     * Adds a custom read more link to all excerpts, manually or automatically generated
     *
     * @param string $post_excerpt Posts's excerpt.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function understrap_all_excerpts_get_more_link( $post_excerpt ) {
        if ( is_admin() || ! get_the_ID() ) {
            return $post_excerpt;
        }

        $permalink = esc_url( get_permalink( (int) get_the_ID() ) ); // @phpstan-ignore-line -- post exists

        return $post_excerpt . ' [...]<p><a class="btn btn-secondary understrap-read-more-link" href="' . $permalink . '">' . __(
            'Read More...',
            'understrap'
        ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text"> from ' . get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) . '</span></a></p>';

    }
}
```

Hoping someone very knowledgeable of WordPress can see a convenient way of integrating excerpt_length into it. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_length/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This luckily works for me:

```
function custom_excerpt_length($excerpt) {
    if (has_excerpt()) {
        $excerpt = wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), apply_filters("excerpt_length", 30));
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter("the_excerpt", "custom_excerpt_length", 999);
```

stumbled across it at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139953/excerpt-length-not-working

Thanks